# how to add value to existing variable in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

```
addGPA(GPA, TotalGPAS):-
            TotalGPAS = GPA + TotalGPAS.
```

I used this way, and it doesn't work.
it says that is "Free variable in expression"
so I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate arithmetic terms use the predicate `is`. This only works if all the variables on the right side are instantiated.

You cannot overwrite variables. If you want to have a different value, use a different variable. And this variable needs to be an additional attribute if you want to use it outside of the current call.

Result:

```
addGPA(GPA, TotalGPAS, NewTotal):-
            NewTotal is GPA + TotalGPAS.
```

Test

```
?- addGPA(1.7, 8.9, T).
T = 10.6.
```

Comment: "right side are unified" should be "right side are instantiated" (i.e. not unbound variables)